# How To Fix Visible and Disable navbar on scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, navbar

I'm setting up new bootstrap web page that contains navbar on the top and slider in middle and  2 sections of content on bottom how I can set a navbar visible when scroll on the top and hide navbar on slider area also re visible navbar on content

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header_aera" id="main_navbar">

 <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav top_nav">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+00 (0) 00 000 0000</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>info@mysite.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Sun - Thu 08:00 - 17:00</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</nav> 


<section class="slider_area row m0">
    <div class="slider_inner">
    <p>this is slider area</p>
</div>
</section>



<section class="professional_builder row">
    <div class="container">
<p>this is first section area</p>
 </div>
</section>



<section class="professional_builder row">
    <div class="container">
<p>this is second section area</p>
 </div>
</section>
```

also I tried this Jq Function

```
 function mainNavbar(){
    if ( $('#main_navbar').length ){ 
         $('#main_navbar').affix({
            offset: {
                top: 10,                                
                bottom: function () {
                    return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
                },

            }
        }); 
    };

};
```

now when I scrolling down the navbar is visible but for whole page I want only visible for content sections not for slider section